# Countries with solely international trains

Tags: trains, international-travel, factoids

All trains in Liechtenstein are international (in fact, they all serve at least three countries).

Are there any other countries with regular passenger train services where all trains are international?

Comment: Hmm, are we counting any kind of train or is urban mass transit/light rail excluded? If it's the latter, I think [Singapore](http://www.seat61.com/Malaysia.htm#Singapore%20Station) qualifies.

Comment: @ZachLipton Do you mean that the *only* metro/light rail in Singapore leaves the country?

Comment: Exactly. I mean that I think Singapore has only international trains if you aren't counting mass transit. If urban mass transit does count, it has an extensive domestic network and so would not qualify.

Comment: What about Laos and Transnistria?

Comment: @AndreyChernyakhovskiy Both seem to work (although of course Transnistria has a disputed states), you can add it as an answer! :)

Answer (score 32, accepted):

[Monaco - Monte-Carlo is the only railway station in the Principality of Monaco](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Monaco-Monte-Carlo)

Comment: Apparently, all trains servicing it are heading from or to Italy, so it's also at least three countries.  And it's serviced by one train serving no less than 8 countries!  (Monaco - Nice - Milan - Innsbruck - Vienna - Warsaw - Minsk - Moscow)

Comment: Nice. The other European micro-states don't qualify: [Andorra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Andorra#Transport) has no railway station at all. [Luxembourg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luxembourg_railway_station) does have domestic trains. [Vatican seems to be unclear.](http://travel.stackexchange.com/a/84542/37733)

Comment: @gerrit Innsbruck and Vienna are in the same country :)

Comment: @IanF1 They are, but the train passes through Czechia en-route from Warsaw to Vienna.  Poland and Austria do not share a border.

Comment: To be pedantic: not sure if you can say that the Czech Republic is *served* by that train then....

Comment: @Oliphaunt, sure, it stops in Bohumin and Breclav.

Comment: Even when [San Marino had a train](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ferrovia_Rimini–San_Marino), it still had multiple stops in the country.

Answer (score 16):

Monaco (another European city-state) has [only one train station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gare_de_Monaco-Monte-Carlo).

Vatican City also [has only one train station](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rail_transport_in_Vatican_City). A [tourist train](http://en.radiovaticana.va/news/2015/09/11/new_weekly_train_tour_from_vatican_city_to_castel_gandolfo_/1171235) serviced it weekly from Italy in 2015, but it is not clear if it is still running.

Comment: Vatican City is not serviced by regular passenger trains, though.  By "regular train traffic" I meant "regular passenger train traffic"; I should have clarified but for a travel site it should be expected this is what I meant.  Monaco is good but pnuts was a couple of minutes faster (sorry).

Comment: There was a weekly [tourist train](http://en.radiovaticana.va/news/2015/09/11/new_weekly_train_tour_from_vatican_city_to_castel_gandolfo_/1171235) in 2015. Has it stopped?

Comment: Interesting, you should add that to your answer (I didn't know and it didn't exist last time I read the Wikipedia article)

Comment: I wouldn't rely too much on Wikipedia here... The [Trenitalia website](http://www.fsitaliane.it/tcom-en) does not know either *Stazione Città del Vaticano* nor *Stazione Vaticana*. (Nor does the [Swiss railyway site](http://www.sbb.ch/), which I, ahem, trust a tiny little bit more.)

Comment: @StephanKolassa The Swiss railway website relies on HAFAS, and thus on Italian or Vatican authorities adding things to HAFAS.  For example, in Spain it is quite incomplete, but that is not the Swiss fault.  It is possible that a weekly tourist train exists but is not listed in HAFAS and not included in standard booking services (certainly museum trains aren't).

Comment: The [Vatican tourist train from the Vatican to Castel Gandolfo](http://www.museivaticani.va/content/museivaticani/en/visita-i-musei/scegli-la-visita/musei-e-collezioni/vaticano-in-treno.html) does appear to still be running.

Comment: [There's also a subway line very close by](https://www.romewise.com/images/charta_roma_060608_with_metro_text.jpg) but it's not clear if it passes directly below Vatican. It doesn't seem to have a _station_ in Vatican though.

Answer (score 6):

At time of writing -- but not for much longer -- the **railway network in Laos** consists of a single station, Thanaleng (near the capital Vientiane), which has passenger services only across the Mekong river to Nong Khai, Thailand:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thanaleng_railway_station

However, in 2021 the Vientiane-Boten link across the country to China is scheduled to open, and this will have a number of domestic stations:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vientiane%E2%80%93Boten_railway

Answer (score 5):

Actually all trains in Liechtenstein are Austrian (since 1872) , with locomotive / conductor change in Buch, Switzerland.

In 1970, the passport control was done (for Switzerland) by a Liechtenstein police officer who got on the train in Buch and off at the first Austrian station Feldkirch without stopping.

On request my passport was stamped with a Liechtenstein stamp.

Answer (score 5):

Since early 2018, there is [passenger train service between Ethiopia and Djibouti](https://www.seat61.com/Ethiopia.htm).  It appears that all trains go from Addis Ababa to Djibouti City, so all trains in both countries are effectively international trains.

However, there are at least two passenger stops in each country, so it is also possible to take this train domestically;  I'm not sure whether this counts under the criteria of the question.  Moreover, [there are other passenger lines under construction in Ethiopia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awash%E2%80%93Weldiya_Railway), and once these are completed and begin passenger service, there will be both domestic and international passenger trains in Ethiopia.